# MATLAB: Read in a specific order lines from a text file

Tags: matlab, file, text

I have a text file that have many lines, each have a number. To plot a line that I want, I need to read the 1st, 2nd and 7th, 8th and 13th, 14th line and s.o. How Do I write the code for this?

I got something from the internet, but I don´t know how to implement my problem with the following code.

```
fileID = fopen([fname 'r'],'r');
% initialize a counter
count = 0;
% keep reading the file
while 1
% get a line of text
R = fgetl(fileID);
count = count + 1;
% exit if the line is empty
if R == -1
    break;
 end
% check modulus of count for every 2nd and 11th line
if mod(count,11) == 1
    tline_2nd = R;
elseif mod(count,2) == 10
    tline_11th = R;
end
end
```

Comment: do the lines start with number, or you just need [1:6:end, 2:6:end]-th lines in the file? Do you want to use the data in the lines immediately after reading and then discard or you want to store all the data for chosen lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to read 2 lines and skip 4 lines, you could do something like this:

Edit: Here is the code to also store the lines. Since I don't know what the lines look like, I saved everything in a cell.

```
fileID = fopen(fname,'r');
% initialize a counter
readnum = 2;
readcount = 0;
skipnum = 4;
R = {}; % Make R a cell array to hold non-uniform data.
% keep reading the file
while 1
    % get a line of text
    line = fgetl(fileID);
    readcount = readcount + 1;
    % exit if the line is empty
    if line == -1
        break;
    end
    if readcount > readnum
        readcount = 1;
        for i = 1:skipnum
            line = fgetl(fileID);
            if line == -1
                break;
            end
        end
    end
    R{end+1} = line;
end
```

Comment: Looks good, but I need to save the data into an array, so R has to be somehow an array, how can I do that?

Comment: Without knowing what the lines of data look like, all I can do right now is store each line into an array. Would that be sufficient?

Comment: This is exactly what I want!, I have only numbers in my Textfile.

Comment: Great! I would appreciate if you registered the answer and upvote. :)